# Plotting dataframe where headers are 24h timestamps

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, time-series

I have a CSV which looks something like:

```
0        1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9      10      11      12      13      14      15      16      17      18      19      20      21      22      23      24
<>                                                                                                                                                                                                
Red   2151.0  1966.0  1889.0  2148.0  2112.0  2351.0  1813.0  2008.0  1841.0  1901.0  2373.0  2643.0  2322.0  1901.0  1849.0  2132.0  1877.0  1963.0  1861.0  1973.0  2468.0  3434.0  3159.0  3413.0
Blue  2122.0  2059.0  2274.0  2647.0  2136.0  2271.0  2107.0  2192.0  2403.0  2148.0  2008.0  2111.0  2061.0  2196.0  2165.0  2354.0  1931.0  2195.0  1985.0  2025.0  2463.0  2943.0  3302.0  3424.0
```

I need to plot this data as a scatter plot, where Red/Blue is on the X-axis, and time on the Y-axis. Here 1->24 is timestamps per hour. I am confused as usually we have a timestamp per row, but in my situation, I have to plot each row, for each timestamp.

I then have multiple such CSVs, and will need to plot all of them to one graph.

So my question is, what's the best way to plot all values of Red/Blue for each given timestamp?

When I try to do:

```
x = sorted_df.index
y = list(sorted_df.columns)


plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.show()
```

I get a `ValueError: x and y must be the same size` - and this is my main source of confusion because x and y will never be the same. In the above example, x will always be 2 and y will always be 24!

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could transpose (`.T`, short for [`.transpose`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html#pandas-dataframe-transpose)) your dataframe, iterate its (now) columns and add the scatter plot of each column ("Red", "Blue", etc.) in the same plot:

```
# Assuming that your index is ["Red", "Blue", ...]
# Assuming that your columns are [1, 2, ...]
sorted_df = sorted_df.T
# Now your index is [1, 2, ...] and columns are ["Red", "Blue", ...]

for column in sorted_df.columns:
    # x: [1, 2, ...] (always the same)
    # y: Values for each column (first "Red", then "Blue", and so on)
    plt.scatter(sorted_df.index, sorted_df[column])

# Display plot
plt.show()
```

This is the result I get:

[image: Scatter plot from sample data]

Comment: Quick question. What if I wanted to plot all the values for a single value on X-axis. So plot all of these values, for a single value. Cause I have multiple CSVs, x-axis can just have each of the CSVs, and Y-axis all of the plots.

Comment: You mean multiple xaxis ranges? BEcause that should be feasible by sugin this exact same code. Can you provide an example?

Comment: Basically, can I plot all the values for a single value "x-axis". So say the x-axis is the name of the file/ or the date. and plot all the values on the Y axis for the single x-axis. I try to do it but it says "X and Y must be the same size"

Comment: I don't get it. I get that your x-axis will be a file name, but the y-axis will be a bunch of values? Is this because the CSV are grouped by hourly data? Because "X and Y must be the same size" is important to define your variables cleverly